# How to open dropdown on hover in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Right now my navigation drop down can open on click.

I want it to open upon hover. How do I do this?

Comment: You want to open on click ? or you doesn't ? not clear your question

Comment: I think he just wants to open the drop-down on hover like this: https://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/frDqh

Comment: @Hkachhia I wanted to open on hover.

Answer (score 20):

simply add following css

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5n91f3db/)

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
 
<ul class="navbar-nav">

  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown link
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It also helps to add some `padding-bottom: 0.5rem;` on main the **<a>** to keep the dropdown deployed a bit more time (the mouse movements tend to affect it sometimes)

Comment: Note that html id name should not be camelCase

Answer (score 7):

The css from Znaneswar works great but I would add this line as well.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  margin: -0.125rem 0 0;
}
```

The dropdown is spaced 0.125rem away from the element that spawns the dropdown.  So you'll have a hard time navigating from the link to the dropdown without it disappearing when you mouse over that gap.

And if you want the dropdown link to actually be a link as well, just remove this attribute from the a tag

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
```

Answer (score 6):

Below css works fine

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle:active {
    pointer-events: none;   // Add this, to prevent clicking dropdown's default click function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown">
...
</div>
```

You could try this with jQuery:

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function(){
$(this).addClass("show");
});
```

Comment: I don't get the downvote. The OP didn't request a CSS only solution.

Comment: I don't think this solution will work since it adding a class but it doesn't remove it when element is not on hover effect anymore

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution using Angular with ng-bootstrap and bootstratp:

CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
display: block;}
```

HTML:

```
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" ngbDropdown>
        <a class="nav-link h5 dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" ngbDropdownToggle>
          Parent</a>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" ngbDropdownItem>Child1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" ngbDropdownItem>Child2</a>
          </div>
      </li>
```

So, if don't use the CSS property, the dropdown will happens only when click on parent link.

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate the answers to this question, the answers given are seemingly not the best. This is because these answers are disregarding accessibility.

Notice that, when using only CSS to make the dropdown show on `.nav-link` hover, the `aria-expanded` parameter on the `.nav-link` element does not change to true.

You must use some JS then in order to have the full range of accessibility functionality.

Below is what I have come up with to combat this.

```js
// header_scripts.js

$('body').on('hover', '.nav-item.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

```css
/* header.css */

.dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

The above code should provide the same functionality that you are seeing in the other answers to this question, but with full accessibility concerns.

The CSS I gave is very general and has pretty low specificity so work with that as you see fit.